# How to align database output in text file using sql query

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an issue while opening the text file of database output. The null value columns are replaced with the columns which have data. So the data is not properly formatting in the text file. I generated the text file from oracle sql developer. And after opening the text file I can see the alignment of columns is not proper(misplacing of values between null  columns and columns which have data ). Can anyone please help me to solve this issue

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS  (and SQL client tools) tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: It would be helpful to edit the question and show what you are talking about.

Comment: how are you generating this text file from the database? and can you show us an example? Otherwise you're asking us to guess.

Comment: Can you debug code that you cannot see?  Hmm . . .

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here, but - what you said reminds me of this. Example is based on Scott's `EMP` table where some employees have `NULL` in the `COMM` column:

```
SQL> select ename, job, comm, deptno
  2  from emp
  3  where deptno = 30;

ENAME      JOB             COMM     DEPTNO
---------- --------- ---------- ----------
ALLEN      SALESMAN         300         30
WARD       SALESMAN         500         30
MARTIN     SALESMAN        1400         30
BLAKE      MANAGER                      30
TURNER     SALESMAN                     30
JAMES      CLERK                        30

6 rows selected.
```

If you're *spooling* such data by concatenating columns, you get mess which is difficult to read:

```
SQL> select ename||'-'||job||'-'||comm||'-'||deptno
  2  from emp
  3  where deptno = 30;

ENAME||'-'||JOB||'-'||COMM||'-'||DEPTNO
----------------------------------------------------------
ALLEN-SALESMAN-300-30
WARD-SALESMAN-500-30
MARTIN-SALESMAN-1400-30
BLAKE-MANAGER--30
TURNER-SALESMAN--30
JAMES-CLERK--30

6 rows selected.
```

But, if you right-pad strings to certain length (`RPAD` function) and use `NVL` for missing data, then the result is somewhat prettier:

```
SQL> select rpad(ename, 10, ' ') ||'-'||
  2         rpad(job  , 10, ' ') ||'-'||
  3         nvl(to_char(comm, '9990D00'), '        ') ||'-'||
  4         deptno as result
  5  from emp
  6  where deptno = 30;

RESULT
---------------------------------------------------------------------
ALLEN     -SALESMAN  -  300,00-30
WARD      -SALESMAN  -  500,00-30
MARTIN    -SALESMAN  - 1400,00-30
BLAKE     -MANAGER   -        -30
TURNER    -SALESMAN  -        -30
JAMES     -CLERK     -        -30

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```